# github failed to push some refs after branch deletion

Tags: git, github, branch, push

I created a local branch `tabbar` with just 1 commit and pushed it `git push origin tabbar`. Then i decided to make changes to that commit, and ammended them. The remote branch never got merged, so i went to github and pressed Delete Branch. So now i can not push that commit - git gives me

`error: src refspec tabbar does not match any.`

`error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myName/Myproject.git'`, even if i change the name of local branch.

Can some one help me to resolve this? I'm not very familiar with github.

Comment: Did you try to use the `--force` (`-f`) option when you push?

Comment: Yes. still `error: src refspec tabbar2 does not match any.`

Comment: That's a different error. Can you update your post and show the complete push command you use? It should be something like `git push -f origin tabbar`

Comment: It would be interesting with the output of `git remote show origin` and `git branch -vva` too.

Comment: Can you show your current git log?

Answer (score 0):

Though I didn't know why this issue happend, but you can try `git push origin tabbar:tabbar`

Comment: Past 12 hours, i was able to `git push origin tabbar2`. I don't know why, and what happened to guthub that made it accept my commit. So i guess as i don't know the cause/solution for this question, we can call it _resolved itself_.